# "sudo bash" ignoring read-only permission of .bash_history file

Tags: 12.04, bash, sudo

This problem is in an up-to-date 12.04, and seems to have started recently.

I have my .bash_history file set to read only. Lately I've noticed that despite this the file is being modified !
Here's the scenario. 
In a new terminal, here is the tail of the file:

```
$ tail -5 .bash_history 
mkdir -p ttt ; gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r180 -sOutputFile=ttt/p%03d.png *.pdf
rsync -av /home/u1204 /media/SEAGATE/u1204 
gnote.late.reminders|GREP_COLOR='1;32' egrep -i "is overdue"
pvr_iplayer -x -HD /home/u1204/Documents/pvr/tv-hd ; pvr_iplayer -x -STD /home/u1204/Documents/pvr/tv-std
exit
```

open a shell with raised privileges

```
 $ sudo bash [sudo] 
 password for u1204: 

 # ls -l ~/.bash_history
 -r-------- 1 u1204 u1204 1266 Feb 23 19:52 /home/u1204/.bash_history
```

so .bash_history is still definitely read-only.
Do something, then exit the escalated shell:

```
# echo "written to history file"
written to history file

# exit
exit
```

And Voilà, the history file has been modified !

```
$ ls -l ~/.bash_history
-r-------- 1 u1204 u1204 1324 Feb 23 20:10 /home/u1204/.bash_history
```

Open another terminal to confirm:

```
$ tail -5 .bash_history 
pvr_iplayer -x -HD /home/u1204/Documents/pvr/tv-hd ; pvr_iplayer -x -STD /home/u1204/Documents/pvr/tv-std
exit
ls -l ~/.bash_history
echo "written to history file"
exit
```

I'm pretty sure that it didn't used to do this (in 10.04 at least).

Anyway, this can't be correct behaviour, can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root has universal read/write to everything.  Period.

Proponents of windows like to claim its authentication system is stronger because it doesn't have a "god" account and even local administrators can be explicitly denied.

You cannot deny root any access to any thing on the local system.

After some comments, it got me thinking you might be looking for a way to not write to bash history at all.  You could do that like this: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7041/dont-save-commands-in-bash-history-only-for-current-session

Putting unset HISTFILE in your bashrc for those that don't want to follow the link.

Comment: `Root has universal read/write to everything. Period.`  
 I Agree, alas if you use `sudo su -` the above described situation doesn't happen. I think this is the difference he asked about. Correct me if I'm wrong of course.

Comment: I read it differently.  I saw "How do I deny root access to my bash history" and answered with - you can't.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I must be misrembering or am doing something differently, because I don't ever recall t his happening before.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing: Could you (without any special effort) point me to an explanation to why what I describe in my _Answer_ happens? It's quite confusing that what Thorsen describes does happen when you sudo, but when you sudo su -, it doesn't. Much obliged.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2F299345%2Fwhats-the-difference-between-sudo-su-and-sudo-i&l=1

Comment: @catalesia - Your answer is poor for multiple reasons.  One of which is: `sudo su -` makes sure that environment variables are not kept.  Use both invocations of the command `sudo /bin/bash` and `sudo su -i` or google for the difference.  In each, cd ~ and see what happens.  For people that need sudo for non-trivial tasks, enviroment variables are necessary.  So your answer while it may answer a corner case, is incorrect.  Congratulations on convincing me to downvote it now that you kept pushing at it.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing: You misunterstood me. I really wanted to know ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can ultimatively deny access.

```
chattr +i
```

Comment: Fair point.  And it gets an upvote from me

Comment: (i would have commented it into the thread above, yet i was obviously not able to make the UI do it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Thor

> I'm pretty sure that it didn't used to do this (in 10.04 at least).

It actually does.

What I think happens is if you use `sudo`, you still get to keep your *identity* but with lifted privileges, if you used `sudo su -` on the other hand, you would have become the *"real root".* hence the difference.

Comment: okay, I must be misrembering

Answer (score 0):

RO is nothing a program cannot override, as long as you're root or owner of the file. So the correct way is not to set the file to r--, but to execute

unset HISTFILE

For "sudo -s" this should work (environment is copied, exactly the reason why your user's .bash_history is used), for "sudo -i" (like "su -") you're using /root/.bash_history anyway. If you do not want to do this, you need to unset HISTFILE in your root's .bashrc/.bash_profile.

btw: as already mentioned the correct way to get a root-shell is sudo -s / sudo -i. "sudo su" or "sudo bash" works, but its a rather unclean way to do so.